# Swift: Possible to disable implicit string interpolation for struct?

Tags: swift

I use structs that wrap multilingual strings, and it is very easy to accidentally print the struct type name instead of strings, like this:

```
struct MultilangStringStruct {
    let en: String
    let de: String
    
    init(en: String, de: String) {
        self.en = en
        self.de = de
    }
}

let s = MultilangStringStruct(en: "Of course", de: "Jawohl")

/// Oops, we forgot to use s.en, and it prints this, with no compiler warning:
/// Commander said "MultilangString(en: "Of course", de: "Jawohl")"!
print("The commander said \"\(s)\"!")
```

Can I modify the struct somehow to prevent this implicit conversion to string? I would like the swift compiler to produce error or warning, that I can notice, and fix `s` to `s.en`.

Comment: You can customize string interpolation _itself_. (Not for the `print` command, though.)

Comment: You can adopt CustomStringConvertible and barf at runtime, but you cannot make anything happen at compile time, no.

Comment: I assume using `print` isn’t what this is really about so I would try to solve this by writing unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CustomStringConvertible` protocol to customize textual representation.
[Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible)

In the `description` property you can add logging to the console using `os_log` from `os.log` or `NSLog` from `Foundation`.

#### Example

```
import os.log

struct MultilangStringStruct {
    let en: String
    let de: String

    init(en: String, de: String) {
        self.en = en
        self.de = de
    }
}

extension MultilangStringStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        os_log(.error, "Not implemented")
        return "Not implemented"
    }
}

let s = MultilangStringStruct(en: "Of course", de: "Jawohl")

print("The commander said \"\(s)\"!")

// Console output
1968-04-26 01:23:47.346953+0300 YourApp[85507:7491471] MultilangStringStruct: Not implemented
The commander said "Not implemented"!
```

Comment: Yes, I already said that in a comment. But it is not what the OP asked to do.

Comment: Thank you, I could at least call `assertionFailure()` there, and hope this gets caught in development - better than current state, even though I'd prefer compile-time error/warning.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for a way to disable string interpolation for a custom type in a way that would cause a compile time error. I found a way and figured I'd share for anyone else wanting to do this in the future:

You can do it by providing two different interpolations for the type, causing an `Ambiguous use of 'appendInterpolation'` compiler error.

A reusable way to do this could look like this:

```swift
protocol DisableInterpolatePart1 {}
protocol DisableInterpolatePart2 {}
protocol DisableInterpolation: DisableInterpolatePart1, DisableInterpolatePart2 {}
extension DefaultStringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: some DisableInterpolatePart1) {
        appendInterpolation("don't interpolate me!")
    }
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: some DisableInterpolatePart2) {
        appendInterpolation("don't interpolate me!")
    }
}
```

Then add the `DisableInterpolation` protocol conformance to the type for which you want to disable interpolation like this:

```swift
struct MyType: DisableInterpolation {
    let value: String = "Hi"
}
```

Then when you go to interpolate like `print("Value is \(myValue)")` the compiler will complain with an error that says `Ambiguous use of 'appendInterpolation'`:
[image: Ambiguous use of appendInterpolation error when trying to interpolate MyType]

**NOTE:** This does NOT cause a compiler error if you just do `print(myValue)`, it only causes an error when doing string interpolation. This was enough for my use case though.